# "Unauthorized" while selecting forms for associating workflow

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

I am using the latest opensource formsflow.ai v4.0.2. I brought the entire project to my personal laptop. I followed the Docker full installation guide. Docker is running fine. In http://localhost:3000, login as formsflow-designer and selected an existing form for associating workflow, If I select one of the forms it shows :unauthorized" as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "unauthorised" error is due to wrongly configured environment variable for forms-flow designer role (DESIGNER_ROLE_ID). Please refer https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/blob/master/forms-flow-forms/README.md#formsflow-forms-userrole-api for obtaining the required env for roles and use those in the environment variables mentioned in the table https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker#formsflowai-keycloak-variable-settings . And rebuild and deploy forms-flow-web. This should fix your issue.